# Loading images according to search criteria in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out how to load a certain image from a local folder after the user presses the search button. My current code is:

```
<!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
<form method="post">
  <h1>
    SEARCH FOR USERS
  </h1>
  <input type="text" name="search" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>

<!-- [SEARCH RESULTS] -->

<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $r) {
        echo("<table  align='center' width='1800'>");
        echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td width='600' align='left'>$r[name]</td>");
        echo("<td width='600' align='center'>$r[item_type]</td>");
        echo("<td width='600' align='center'>$r[oldname]</td>");
        echo("</tr>");
        echo("</table>");
    }
  } else {
    echo "No results found";
  }
}
?>
```

This part works. It retrieves all the results from the mysql DB. What i want to do next is to retrieve the images from a local folder for each item in the search query. The name of the images are equal to the search query results ($r[name]).

What i am aiming for is something like this:

[image: Example]

Image first -> then name -> then something else etc etc...
I tried a couple of things, being new to php i coudln't figure it out yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is $results query? you have image 'profile' url in the row of user?

Comment: No i do not have the URL for the images in the db. I have only the DB with the users and additional information. The images are in a local folder.

Comment: Also the $results query:   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `etcitem` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
  echo json_encode($results);
}

Comment: edit question not write here all code

Comment: @PeterL path of image folder ?

Comment: Yes it is. It searches the database and returns all of the hits based on the users input.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\SearchImage\Image\

Comment: @PeterL please try to code I shared in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made minor changes in your code hope this will help you

```
<!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
<form method="post">
  <h1>
    SEARCH FOR USERS
  </h1>
  <input type="text" name="search" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>

<!-- [SEARCH RESULTS] -->

<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM etcitem WHERE name LIKE ?"); 
  $stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]); 
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

  if (count($results) > 0) {
    echo("<table  align='center' width='1800'>");
    foreach ($results as $r) {
        echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td width='600' align='left'><img src='/Image/$r[name]'></td>");
        echo("<td width='600' align='center'>$r[item_type]</td>");
        echo("<td width='600' align='center'>$r[oldname]</td>");
        echo("</tr>");
    }
    echo("</table>");
  } else {
    echo "No results found";
  }
}
?>
```